# How to understand and use « avoir que »?

Tags: grammaire, constructions

In my Oxford-Hachette dictionary they use a sentence structure that I have never seen before with « avoir ». They have the following two examples and the translation that follows:

1. « j'ai qu'il m'énerve » he's getting on my nerves, that's what's wrong
2. « j'ai que mon ordinateur ne marche pas » because my computer doesn't work

I don't really understand how this construction works and how « j'ai que mon ordinateur ne marche pas » would differ from « parce que mon ordinateur ne marche pas ». Could someone explain this structure and give some examples of some common usages?

Comment: I would translate it as: What's bothering me or What's wrong with me is that he's getting on my nerves. What's bothering me or What's wrong with me is that my computer doesn't work. And in context, that would be said in response to: **Mais qu'est-ce que tu as?** [uses the verb avoir] As in: What's bothering you? Or What's wrong with you?

Comment: That is an idiomatic usage. If you look further in that dictionary, you should find other examples.

Comment: @Lambie: You seem to be contradicting the reply you made to jiliagre: "It's definitely not What's the problem with you?"

Comment: @HarryAudus No, I am not contradicting anything at all.

Comment: @Lambie: There's no need to get personal. If I'm confused, I ask a question. Is that odd behaviour?


Here's the thing. Your first comment to Quippy was (and I quote): "I would translate it as: What's bothering me or What's wrong with me is that ...".


Then your first comment to jilliagre was (and I quote): "It's definitely not What's the problem with you? Or even happening to you."


These two statements seem to me to be contradictory, but you claimed that "No, what's bothering you? and What's wrong with you? are not the same thing as What's happening to you."

Comment: @Lambie: My response was an example in which "What's bothering you?" and "What's wrong with you?" mean essentially the same thing. To which you've replied that you said that in your first comment to jilliagre. No, you didn't; your reply was "It's definitely not What's the problem with you? Or even happening to you."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these sentences are a reply to ***Qu'est-ce que t'as ?*** (i.e. What's the problem/matter with you?)

The reply could have been *Il m'énerve* or *Mon ordinateur ne marche pas* but often, the verb of the question is echoed in the reply, leading to ***J'ai que*** followed by the explanation of the issue.

Here *J'ai que* is not a colloquial form of *Je n'ai que* (no *ne* is dropped) as it would have been in this different dialogue :

*— Qu'est-ce que tu as ?*  (What do you have ?)
*— J'ai que dix euros.*    (formal speech: *Je n'ai que dix euros*)

If the reply of *Qu'est-ce que tu as ?* happens to work with the verb *avoir*, there is no need to use *que*:

*— Qu'est-ce que tu as ?  (What is happening to you?)

— J'ai le covid.* (I have covid-19) although it is still possible to reply ***J'ai que j'ai le covid***.

Comment: It's definitely not What's the problem with you? Or even happening to you. What's happening to you. is: Qu'est-ce qui t'arrive?

Comment: @Lambie: You seem to be contradicting the reply you made to Quippy: "What's bothering you? Or What's wrong with you?"

Comment: @HarryAudus No, what's bothering you? and What's wrong with you? are not the same thing as What's happening to you. What's **happening** to you? Is: **Qu'est-ce qui t'arrive**? Please read more carefully.

Comment: @Lambie: If I look ill, you could very well say to me either "What's bothering you?" or "What's wrong with you?"

Comment: @HarryAudus Yes, I already said that in my first comment under the answer. Your behavior seems a bit odd, I have to say.

Answer (score 1):

D'accord avec l'analyse d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50396/26366), j'ajouterais que généralement la nature d'un complément d'objet peut varier (nom, pronom, proposition conjonctive introduite par *que*, infinitf etc.) et qu'avec certains verbes on a une restriction de la nature pour exprimer ce complément. Avec le verbe *avoir* on a généralement uniquement des noms ou des pronoms, parfois des verbes à l'infinitif ; mais dans la langue parlée familière, à une réponse comme « qu'as-tu ? », on répond parfois en donnant une proposition entière comme objet direct, qu'on introduit avec la conjonction [*que*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Conjonction_1), comme on le ferait plus régulièrement avec d'autres verbes qui ne sont pas aussi « sélectifs » (*je vois que vous êtes au courant*). (LBU14, § 298,299)